# Does this video show a water droplet in gravitational orbit?

Tags: physics

[Andrew Rader](http://andrew-rader.com), an author and engineeer, [tweeted a GIF video](https://twitter.com/marsrader/status/726250075979169792) showing a droplet of water rotating around some sort of probe. [image]

> Everything has gravity - here's a droplet of water orbiting a needle in 0G.

No source is provided. The scale is unclear. The result is counter-intuitive, and I am skeptical.

I realize that there is a stitching point somewhere to make the GIF repeat. I'm not challenging that aspect.

**Does this video show a water droplet in (gravitational) orbit around a needle?**

Comment: I'm curious now quite how slow a water droplet would have to travel to actually orbit a needle (assuming you could actually set this system up far enough from any other masses for it to work at all.)

Comment: @reirab For a rough approximation let's take a much more massive needle (say, M = 0.1 kg), also join all its mass in a ball (the mass of a needle is mostly "far away" and thus pulls less). And let the droplet orbit at a distance of just 1 mm. Then the orbital speed for a circular orbit is approximately sqrt(G M / r) or about 80 micrometers per second (i.e., during a full day it moves by just about half a centimeter)

Comment: The camera has more gravity than the water droplet.

Comment: @PyRulez depends how close the camera is to the needle...

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The GIF was sourced from the [International Space Station video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHrBhgwq__Q) by astronaut Don Pettit. The video depicts small water droplets orbiting a polyethylene knitting needle which was charged by rubbing it with a piece of paper. Don Petitt states that the blue knitting needles are "8mm in diameter".

In the video, Don Pettit clearly says that the attractions are electrostatic, and not gravitational in nature.

A transcript of the relevant section for those who can't watch the video (starting around 0:50, emphasis mine)

> This is like a little satellite going around a cylindrical shaped planet , except the physics here is a little different, it's **not about gravitation**, it's about charge forces, and of course charges can exert a potential field as we call it, so it can exert a force at a distance with no tangible connection.

Comment: Now that I have thought about this I so wish to see a charged balloon in space with water flowing around it in a spiral :O . I mean, I get it would be hard to do, but should be possible xD .

Comment: The Twitter feed linked in the question features a tweet by @DanWeaver_ca that links to a [PDF with a paper about that experiment ("Electrostatic Model Applied to ISS Charged Water Droplet Experiment")](http://www.electrostatics.org/images/ESA_2015_I1_Stevenson.pdf).

Comment: A non gravitational orbit? What a time to be alive. That's the first time I've ever said that non-sarcastically.

Comment: Some good sources of info: [The Parallel Between Gravity and Electrostatics](http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/semester2/c02_gravity.html),
[Comparison of Electrostatic & Gravitational Force](https://goforaplusplus.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/comparison-of-electrostatic-gravitational-force/)